# Dynamically add SVG circle in a SVG group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I am using SnapSVG library. I am trying to add a dynamically created SVG circle into a SVG group. A new circle is added every time I click a link (Add Composite). Then I try to push that newly created circle to an array and pass the array to the group (drag) function. I basically want to drag all the circles and rectangle as a group. But its not working. Here is my code ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg id="svg"></svg>
    <div id="addComp">Add Composite</div>

    <script>
// JavaScript Document
(function() {
    var s = Snap("#svg");

    // Construct Composite
    function composite(y, i) {
        var CirArray = [];
        $("svg g").remove();
        $("svg rect").remove();
        $("svg circle").remove();
        var square = s.rect(30, 40, y, 40);
        console.log("Square:" + y);
        square.attr({
            fill: 'lightblue',
            stroke: 'lightblue',
            //strokeOpacity: .3,
            //strokeWidth: 10
        });
        CirArray.push(square);


        var k = 0;
        for (z = 1; z <= i; z++) {
            k = k + 45;
            console.log("Circle:" + k);

            var mycircle = s.circle(k, 120, 20);
            mycircle.attr({
                fill: 'coral',
                stroke: 'coral',
                strokeOpacity: .3,
                strokeWidth: 10
            });

            CirArray.push(mycircle);

        } // For loop end
        drag.apply(null, CirArray);

    } // Construct Composite End

    // Group
    function drag(CirArray) {
        var tableset = s.group(CirArray);
        for (p = 0; p < CirArray.length; p++) {
            console.log(CirArray[p])
        }
        console.log(CirArray.length)
            // Drag
        var move = function(dx, dy) {
            this.attr({
                transform: this.data('origTransform') + (this.data('origTransform') ? "T" : "t") + [dx, dy]
            });
        }
        var start = function() {
            this.data('origTransform', this.transform().local);
        }
        var stop = function() {
            console.log('finished dragging');
        }
        tableset.drag(move, start, stop);
    } //Drag End

    // Add Composite
    var x = 0;
    var clct = 0;
    $("#addComp").click(function() {
        x = x + 45;
        clct = clct + 1;
        composite(x, clct);
    }); // Add Composite End
}()); // Iffe End
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Visit this site and click on 'Add composite' link a couple of times to see it in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/8zan0L6buhffJOluDZET?p=preview)

Any help is very appreciated ....

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basically adding the array on the .group(CirArray) does not seem to add all the array items into a group (Inspect the SVG output) the group  tag is empty.

Instead adding them in the for-loop below. Made the following changes and it seems to work as expected and moving all squares and circles together.

```
  var tableset = s.group();

  for (p = 0; p < CirArray.length; p++) {
        tableset.add(CirArray[p]);
        console.log(CirArray[p])
    }
```

In the drag function also calling it simply drag(cirArray) (as suggested by @Paul-lebeau ie.  drag(CirArray);).

[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fVzDEX85dagy5n22us2Q?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Rafi, I already solved it by getting some help from http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.g My solution was very similar to what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to the `function.apply()` method is supposed to be an array of parameters.

But you are passing in an array of Snap elements.  So in your `drag()` function, the `CirArray` parameter is getting set to the first element of your original `CirArray`, not the whole array.

Either change the call to

```
drag.apply(null, [CirArray]);
```

or just call it normally

```
drag(CirArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both options. They give me this error .... 

**Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name.**

on console.log(CirArray.length)

Comment: That's a different issue you will need to debug.